# async / await. Js не попадает в одну строчку

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, async-await

Пишу на чистом JS.

***Проблема:***

Есть кнопка по нажатию - изменяет департамент в БД.

Попадаю в сервисы, а потом в метод `editRequest()`, он отрабатывает без проблем.

Но после, мне нужно сделать `redirect`.

```
editDepartment = async departmentDto => {
        await basicService.editRequest('/api/rest/departments', departmentDto);// всё ок
        window.location.replace('/api/departments');//пропускает
    }

editRequest = async (url, body) => {
    return await this.sendData(url, body, 'PATCH');
}

sendData = async (url, body = null, method = 'POST') => {
        const headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
        const init = {
            method: method,
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
            headers: headers
        }

    let response = await fetch(url, init)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status < 400) {
                return response.json();
            }
        });

    return response;
    }
```

Если при отладке поставить бряку на строке с "`.then(response => {`", метода "*`sendData`*", то всё отработает как часы.
Сижу с этой проблемой уже 2 сутки. Не пойму, где допускаю ошибку.

Comment: а если не ставить бряку, то что происходит? в консоли например или где что как? результат не приходит? или что?

Comment: у тебя всё так же проблемы с асинхронностью... сделай sendData  как async. и делай `let response = await fetch(... ....... return await response.json();`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если не ставить бряку, то данные в бд обновляются, но редирект не происходит.
В консоли никаких ошибок нет.

я добавил указанный вами код, но это ничего не изменило.

Comment: Я не силён в `JavaScript`, но мне кажется тут либо `await`, либо `.then`, что-то одно. Может убрать `.then` и просто `if` дальше сделать? Сейчас я не понимаю, к чему `await` относится в такой конструкции. Хотя я может и не прав.

Comment: И вот тут возможно тоже `await` нужен, хотя я тоже не уверен `return response.json()` -> `return await response.json()`?

Comment: @CrazyElf Добавил, но к сожалению не сработало. В любом случае спасибо за помощь!